# How to make VS2017 show error where async Task is not awaited?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-await, visual-studio-2017

When converting a large project and migrating to `async`, one easy mistake is to forget awaiting them everywhere. Now the cs compiler will complain whenever we call a task and not await it, **ONLY** when this call is made from inside another async method.
In synchronous methods, cs will remain silent, but you'll be bitten at runtime.
I tried treating all warnings as errors, but nothing is changed, as I was not getting warnings in the first place.

So here is my question: Is there any way to make vs 2017 complain about not awaiting `async Task`s from everywhere, including from non-async methods?

If you're aware of any light-weight and free add-on (not resharper, for instance), that can solve this, it would be appreciated as well.

Comment: By default VS shows it as warning "The async methods lack await" in warning panel

Comment: @Eldho Strangely, it will only show this warning when you call (but not await) an async mthod from inside another async method. No warning is shown when you call the async method from a synchronous method.

Comment: Could you add pseudo code which is easy to visualize

Comment: Oh I guess this happens when the called method returns a `Task` but is not known to be `async`. This happens a lot when you are calling the `async` method through an `interface`.